# Alternative to having to select device every time I run an Android application?

Tags: android, eclipse, dialog, device

Is there some way to have Eclipse NOT present the Android Device Chooser dialog every time I run the Android application I'm developing?  I'm using a running Android device, not an AVD.  There's got to be some place I can set my default device to be the Android device so that I don't have to double-click on the device entry in the ADC dialog everytime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click the Eclipse menu button `run` -> `run configurations` -> `android application` -> `your project name` -> `target` and select `automatic`

Note that this will only work if the device's api level is >= your project's build api level. For instance if you are building against 2.1 but running 1.6 on your phone you will still get the Android Device Chooser. You will also notice that there is a red X to the left of your device in this case.